# IFERROR STATEMENT WITHIN VLOOKUP

Tags: if-statement, excel-2010, vlookup

I asked for help on another formula earlier which has lead to another head scratcher for me.  I'm sure there is probably a way to use IFERROR somewhere in the formula below, but I can't seem to figure out where.  I have a few columns returning #N/A that I just need to be blank.

Everything is working how it should except for the error.  I have another formula feeding off of the results of this formula that I need to populate either Y or N based on the results.  The #N/A is throwing some of them off.

```
=IF(J2="",VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet1!B:F,5,FALSE),"PICKED UP")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap it like this:

```
=IF(J2="",IFERROR(VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet1!B:F,5,0),"Error msg here"),"PICKED UP")
```

`IFERROR` will evaluate the first expression (here, it's the `VLOOKUP`) and if it returns an error, it will return the second part of the formula, which is `Error msg here` in this case. Change it to whatever you want to.

Also, you can use `0` to mean `FALSE` in excel (and `1` to mean `TRUE`).

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(J2="", IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet1!B:F,5,FALSE)), "", VLOOKUP(B2,Sheet1!B:F,5,FALSE)),"PICKED UP")
```

Comment: That formula is giving me a #NAME? error where the #N/A used to be